# How to use Iot.Device.Bindings nuget package on Windows uwp app?

Tags: c#, uwp, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I have Windows UWP foreground app running on my raspberry (windows 10 iot core). I want to use Iot.Device.Bindings nuget package to capture data from various sensors (e.g. bme680). But looks like this package is unsupported on UWP:

```
NU1202: Package Iot.Device.Bindings 1.2.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.17763 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17763). Package Iot.Device.Bindings 1.2.0 supports:
  - net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
```

I tried to create backroung job for iot core, but same error.
Can someone suggest approch how to achive that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: were you able to get this to work with answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Iot.Device.Bindings package does not support UWP on Windows IoT Core but works for .net core. Since the library uses APIs in namespace System.Decive.*. For UWP app, you need to use APIs in namespace Windows.Device.*. At the moment, I can not find a package which is implemented for various sensors. Here are two suggestion for that:

1. Create a .net core app which uses the Iot.Device.Bindings nuget package, and build a channel to send the data from .net core app to your UWP app, such as tcp, or web API.
2. Imeplement the library for UWP by referring the source code.